# Find length of the string between two given special character

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Is there any simplest way to find  length of the string between two given special charcter.

Something like this :

```
select string from table1 where len(string) between '-' and ','
```

for example : `341267-8763,68978`

The query should return 4 (that is the length of 8763)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT CHARINDEX(',', '341267-8763,68978') - CHARINDEX('-', '341267-8763,68978') - 1

4
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `CHARINDEX()` function

```
select string, CHARINDEX(',', string) - CHARINDEX('-', string) Lengths
from table t
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please use CHARINDEX(MatchCharacter,SourceString)**

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(2000),
@startChar VARCHAR,
@EndChar VARCHAR

SET @string = 'It is a established @fact that #a reader'
SET @startChar = '@' 
SET @EndChar = '#'

SELECT @string Source, CHARINDEX(@EndChar, @string) - CHARINDEX(@startChar, @string) - 1 LENGTH
```

**Result**

```
Source                                      LENGTH
------------------------------------------- -----------
It is a established @fact that# a reader    10
```